# OpenGL buffer problem when adding >= 2^16 numbers

Tags: opengl, buffer, floatbuffer

I'm facing some strange difficulties with OpenGL buffer. I tried to shrunk the problem to the minimum source code, so I created program that increment each number of the FloatBuffer in each iteration. When I am adding less than 2^16 float numbers to the FloatBuffer, everything works just fine, but when I add >= 2^16 numbers, then the numbers are not incrementing and stays the same in each iteration.

Renderer:

```
public class Renderer extends AbstractRenderer {
    int computeShaderProgram;
    int[] locBuffer = new int[2];
    FloatBuffer data;
    int numbersCount = 65_536, round = 0; // 65_535 - OK, 65_536 - wrong

    @Override
    public void init() {
        computeShaderProgram = ShaderUtils.loadProgram(null, null, null, null, null,
                "/main/computeBuffer");
        glGenBuffers(locBuffer);
        // dataSizeInBytes = count of numbers to sort * (float=4B + padding=3*4B)
        int dataSizeInBytes = numbersCount * (1 + 3) * 4;

        data = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(dataSizeInBytes)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        initBuffer();
        printBuffer(data);

        glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, locBuffer[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glShaderStorageBlockBinding(computeShaderProgram, 0, 0);

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    private void initBuffer() {
        data.rewind();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++) {
            data.put(i*4,  r.nextFloat());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        if (round < 5) {
            glUseProgram(computeShaderProgram);
            glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, locBuffer[0]);
            glDispatchCompute(numbersCount, 1, 1);
            glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
            glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, data);
            printBuffer(data);
            round++;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Compute buffer

```
#version 430
#extension GL_ARB_compute_shader : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object : enable

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(binding = 0) buffer Input {
    float elements[];
}input_data;

void main () {
    input_data.elements[gl_WorkGroupID.x ] = input_data.elements[gl_WorkGroupID.x] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> glDispatchCompute(numbersCount, 1, 1);
> ```

You **must not** dispatch a compute shader workgroup count exceeding the corresponding [`GL_MAX_GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGet#Compute_Shaders) for each dimension. The spec guarantees that limit to be at least `65535`, so it is very likely that you just exceed the limit on your implementation. Actually, you should be getting a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error for that call, and you should really consider using a [debug context and debug message callback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) to have such obvious errors easily spotted during development.